# showing error " list indices must be integers or slices, not str "

Tags: api, csv, django-rest-framework

> showing error like "list indices must be **integers** or slices, not **str**"
>
> Here MY APIView

```
class UploadViewSet(APIView):
parser_classes = (MultiPartParser, FormParser)
permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
 
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    file = request.POST.get("content")
    data = StringIO(file)
    reader = csv.reader(data, delimiter=',')

    for row in reader:
        new_company = Company(
                    name=row['name'],
                    hr_name=row['hr_name'],
                    hr_email=row['hr_email'],
                    hr_verified=row['hr_verified'],
                    user_id=row['user_id'],
                    primary_phone=row['primary_phone'],
                    comments=row['comments'],
                   )
        new_company.save()
    return Response({"status": "success"},status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

Comment: anybody know the answer?

Comment: try to use a DictReader, like this: reader = csv.DictReader(data, delimiter=',')

Comment: yes its working

Comment: one more thing ,how to check validation while the submitted string is random or invalid string?